# Updating/repairing Knowte

Tags: updates

I can't seem to enter a note on Knowte

[Knowte Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB1eD.png)

I tried clicking the [ + ] button on the button right but it still doesnn't work

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install knowte
```

Results

sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install knowte

```
...:~$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install knowte
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "knowte", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install knowte"

E: Unable to locate package knowte
...:~$ sudo snap install knowte
snap "knowte" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

[Terminal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25yS3.png)

Thank you for looking into this.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is shipped as [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/knowte). The latest version is 2.0.4, it has no alternatives. You may want to try the [AppImage@2.0.4](https://github.com/digimezzo/knowte/releases) too for comparison.